# Select2 js custom CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have problem on changin the Select2 Style. now currently i am using  Tailwind CSS. but the Select2 css will override it and make it different than other element, how to customize this?, thank you

HTML :

```
<link stylesheet tailwind here>
<link stylesheet select2 here>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

already swap the css position, but the result are same

Comment: it's impossible to answer because there's no information on those css rules here. In general a given css attribute wins over another according on which rule, setting that attribute, has higher specificity. The trick to make an attribute of a rule winning over any other (as long as the rules haven't the same specificity) is adding `!important`.. but this would be highly disputed here because it's bad practice. The order of appearence becomes a factor only when rules have the same exact specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: got the problem. CSS on select2 almost all of them using !important. thats why my style is not working

Comment: What version are you using? https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.css there is only one limited case `.select2-hidden-accessible`.

Comment: @ThomasJunk yes i am using the exact version that you share. ok i ll try

Answer (score 1):

create `tailwind.config.js` file in root of your project
then put this code in it:

```js
module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

this `important` option lets you control whether or not Tailwind’s utilities should be marked with !important.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to change order of link tag css file Like this :

```
<!-- from this -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2.css">
<!-- to this -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tailwind.css">
```

Comment: I already describe "already swap the css position, but the result are same". not working

Comment: how do you know that the specificity of the select2 css rules won't be higher than tailwind rules? I'm not sure that strategy would be enough

Comment: when we use this order tailwind css style override the select2 css style. because code run top to bottom approach and the same class style override according to order of css file

Comment: you ignored my point about specificity and I spent tons of words about it here. if a rule has higher specificity it just wins over the other ... regardless of the fact it was defined before or after. (higher specificity is given by an id selector for example.. or inline styling for example. Read the posted link above for further info. Anyway this answer is wrong and the OP told you also it's not working..the only reason I didn't dowvote was to not force you to delete it

Comment: This is a good source on _specificity_: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: the better source for that is mdn as posted as a comment in the question imho